# Customized Google maps on iOS to a dark color

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to customize my google map view as block color can any one please provide any suggestions regarding this.

I have found a link:  [***`MapBox`***](https://tiles.mapbox.com/newmap#2/14.4/-2.6) this may be use furll to me,

but there is no clue how to use this sdk, and wether it is open source or paid sdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pricing for MapBox is here:

http://www.mapbox.com/plans/

And info on their iOS SDK is here:

http://www.mapbox.com/tour/#section-ios-sdk

There is a feature request to add styling support to the google maps SDK here:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4968